# Why my code snaps off the browser window when ran in console?

Tags: javascript, arrays

When I ran the code in browser console or in js fiddle, this code snaps off the browser. I don't understand why it does. Can some one show some light ?

```
var sample = [1, 2, 3, 4];

function arrDupli(sample) {
  var mysample = sample;
    for (var i = 0; i < sample.length; i++) {
      mysample.push(sample[i]);
   }
  console.log(mysample);
}

arrDupli(sample);
```

Comment: "Snap off"? Do you mean it hangs because of the infinite loop?

Comment: "this code snaps off the browser." means what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are creating an infinite loop, `mysample` and `sample` have both the same value, so you are basically just pushing the same value over and over.

Try creating and empty array instead `var mysample = [];`